# Reading data from a *.txt file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to use the data from a .txt file to get the sum of all the values.
I used the function fgets to get all the values. How can I sum all the values??
I tried to make an array for every line in order to sum but I couldnt get it.
Hier is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 256
// La máxima cantidad de líneas que puede tener
#define TOTAL_LINES 52
#define FILE_NAME "test.txt"


int main()
{
    char all_lines[TOTAL_LINES][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char buferFile[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    FILE *document = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    if (document == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be open");
        return 0;
    }
    int index = 0;
    
    while (fgets(buferFile, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, document))
    {
        strtok(buferFile, "\n");
        memcpy(all_lines[index], buferFile, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        index++;
    }
    fclose(document);
    
    
    char line1[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    strcpy(line1,all_lines[1]); 
 
    char *token;
    int j = 0;
    token = strtok(line1, "  ");
    char *array[256];

    while( token != NULL ) {
    array[j++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, "  ");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 256; j++) 
        printf("\n%s", array[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1VuC.png)

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Post your data here instead of an external link.  You would typically convert text to an number (`atoi()`, `atol()`, `strtol()`, `strtoul()` etc).  Another good option here is using `fscanf(bufferFile, "%d", &i)` as it will parse the space separated numbers for you.

Comment: I couldnt post a image cause I'am a new user so instead of a image a link is posted.

Comment: Images requires us to transcribe your data which is a waste of our time.  We would like you to post the data as text either as code or a markdown table.  External links break which makes your question incomplete in time.

Comment: `printf("\n%s", array[j]);` is a problem when `array[j]` was not set by the prior `while( token != NULL ) { array[j++] = token; ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading strings into a 2D array, then storing pointers (`array[]`) to a copy of only the 2nd line you've loaded (`all_lines[1]`). It's not easy to see what your objective is, but I offer this for educational purposes...

```
void main( void ) {
    char buf[ 256 ];

    char *fName = "test.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen( fName, "r" );
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf( "Cannot open '%s'\n", fName );
        return;
    }

    int accum = 0;
    while( fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), fp ) ) {
        for( char *tok = buf; ( tok = strtok( tok, " ") ) != NULL; tok = NULL )
            accum += atoi( tok );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```

**Update:**

In response to a question from the OP, here's an alternative, expanded version of that one line `for()` loop tokenising each row read-in:

```
char *tok = buf;
while( ( tok = strtok( tok, " ") ) != NULL ) {
    accum += atoi( tok );
    tok = NULL;
}
```

The 1st time `strtok()` is called, 'tok' is pointing at 'buf'. For each subsequent call, the value of 'tok' is NULL...

Comment: Thanks. It worked out. Let me ask you why it is needed to use a pointer(*tok)  when you use strtok()?? I have seen many examples and I cannot undestand.

Comment: @Carlos41290 I've updated my response to your question.